# Appium getting textInput value does not work

Tags: react-native, appium

Running a react-native project , where I want to access the value of input field using accessibilityId but after upgrading from react native 44 to react native 49

`element.getAttribute("value");` does not seem to work.

Running :

`node: 8.5.0`

`react-native: 0.49.0`

`appium: 1.7.0`

Comment: Can you share your code ? So that people can check that out easily

Comment: any development on this? I think we have the same problem

Comment: @GuySegal we could not make it work using the accessibilityId so we reverted back to xpath and it started working.

Comment: @BharadwajSampath Did you have problems selecting other elements using accessibilityId  or is it a specific TextInput regression?

Comment: It was a custom textinput wrapped inside a touchable. We also observed that it was some times not working for a normal textinput as well. Did u try finding the value using macaca doctor ?

Answer (score 0):

I had pasted my working code its java appium code hope works to you.

```
String errorC = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@content-desc=\"testPassword\"]")).getText();
System.out.println(errorC);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing , but appium seemed to be very flaky and we are now using wix/detox (https://github.com/wix/detox/) for our automation tests.

Comment: Man you had posted in appium and reactnative you had  change the tag that will be easy to you.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:**
I use `await inputElement.getText();`.

**Details:**

I tried `await inputElement.getValue();` but I got the error `unknown "value" attribute` which is still an [opening issue](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/2726#issuecomment-898899961) and its repo is archived now.

Version:

- appium": 1.21.0
- webdriverio: 7.7.5"